# A batch file to do multiple tasks

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I'm new here and have a question.

How can i write a batch file to do the following multiple tasks:

1. close program "A"
2. open program "B" for 10 minutes
3. close program "B"
4. open program "A"

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try:

```
@echo off
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /IM A_process.exe
start B_process.exe
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 600 /NOBREAK
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /IM B_process.exe
start A_process.exe
exit
```